# Overwriting my local branch with remote branch

Tags: git

I have completely fubar'd my local branch, and would like to start over. The version on the server is correct.

I don't want to start over, I would like to use my local history to fix my huge screwup. (I can if I have to.)

`git fetch branchname`, and `git pull branchname` don't work. The message I get is "*up to date*" however, my local version does not match that of the server.

`git pull origin/branchname` gives me a "*not found*" error.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

First, create a new branch in the current position (in case you need your old 'meesed up' history):

```
git branch fubar-pin
```

Update your list of remote branches and sync new commits:

```
git fetch --all
```

Then, reset your branch to the point where origin/branch points to:

```
git reset --hard origin/branch
```

**Be careful**, this will remove any changes from your *working tree*!

Comment: +1 but you might want to add a reminder to do `git fetch origin` before the reset

Comment: I did this with one slight change and it didn't work: git fetch --all, git reset --hard SHA1OFANOLDCOMMIT, (some other stuff), git reset --hard origin/branch. The end result was that I was still at the old commit. So, this approach may work in some cases, but I think it doesn't work in all.

Comment: @greggles: Any errors? After the last command, HEAD must point at origin/branch.

Comment: fyi, i did this to revert the master branch and it cleared commits i had in other branches. luckily i thought to copy my web folder before doing this.

Comment: @Gavin: no, this will under no circumstances affect other branches than `origin/branch`. Never.

Comment: @knittl how would you it if you want all your branches on remote to have equal values with the one you have locally in a single command? is this possible?

Comment: @yin03: `git push origin +branch1 +branch2 +branchN`, will push all branches you specify. With a globbing refspec (something like `refs/*:refs/*`) you would be able to push all local branches without naming them explicitely (and also create the missing ones)

Comment: @greggles I know this is _very_ late but for other people wondering why that might happen, this approach will only work if you have a branch checked out. It did not work for you because you were in [detached HEAD state](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/detached-head-when-checkout-commit), (HEAD points at a commit, not a branch) and these commands only work if HEAD is pointing at a branch. When you do `git reset` while HEAD is pointing at a branch, that branch will follow.

Answer (score 66):

What I do when I mess up my local branch is I just rename my broken branch, and check out/branch the upstream branch again:

```
git branch -m branch branch-old
git fetch remote
git checkout -b branch remote/branch
```

Then if you're sure you don't want anything from your old branch, remove it:

```
git branch -D branch-old
```

But usually I leave the old branch around locally, just in case I had something in there.

Comment: This seems like the best answer. It helps create a backup copy just in case and seems very likely to result in the local branch being an exact copy of the remote one.

Comment: Great answer, useful to me.  One Q:
The official git-checkout documentation seems to say that your 3rd command should be:
`git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`
Does yours work equally well, without the `--track` ?

Comment: I think the config var `branch.autoSetupMerge` (which I think defaults to true) makes the `--track` implicit. And, yes, in all my git setups I don't need to explicitly `--track` when doing a `checkout -b`, but YMMV.

Answer (score 5):

Your local branch likely has modifications to it you want to discard.  To do this, you'll need to use `git reset` to reset the branch head to the last spot that you diverged from the upstream repo's branch.  Use `git branch -v` to find the sha1 id of the upstream branch, and reset your branch it it using `git reset SHA1ID`.  Then you should be able to do a `git checkout` to discard the changes it left in your directory.

Note: always do this on a backed-up repo.  That way you can assure you're self it worked right.  Or if it didn't, you have a backup to revert to.

Comment: This feels like it would probably work, but given the simplicity and reliability of the approach of "make a copy of your work somewhere else, make a fresh copy of the remote branch" I fail to see how this is better.

Answer (score 2):

```
git reset --hard
```

This is to revert all your local changes to the origin head